# Android : AlertDialog doesn't show

Tags: java, android

I just started learning Android programming and got problem : `My alert dialog's don't show up`.

My idea : When app have been launched, it automatically checks if device is connected to internet, and gives suggestions (By alert dialog's).

I really hope, that some one have solution, because I was looking in many tutorials, but every where was code that starts with `onClickListener` (Button)

Code Snippet:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checkConnection();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}


void checkConnection() {
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    AlertDialog.Builder connectionAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    if (wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting ()) {
        // Do nothing
    } else if (mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting ()) {

        connectionAlert.setMessage("We recommend to use wifi, enable it?");
        connectionAlert.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Wifi has been enabled!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        connectionAlert.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        connectionAlert.show();

    } else {

        connectionAlert.setMessage("Please, enable internet connection!");
        connectionAlert.setNeutralButton("Wifi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Wifi has been enabled!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        connectionAlert.setNeutralButton("Mobile Data", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,"Mobile Data has been enabled!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        connectionAlert.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        connectionAlert.show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you are not connecting to WiFi? The first thing to do is commenting out the `if - else if - else` piece and check if the alert is working fine without any condition to its visibility. If its working fine, you are probably falling in the first if, where no alert is shown. BTW why are you calling `finish()`? Let's remove it and check if the alert is shown correctly before changing `Activity`

Comment: 1.Yes, I'm not connected with wifi 2.It all worked with "Toast" 3.I was using finish(), because of tutorial.(Removed it, nothing changes). 4.I just found out, if i copy this code and paste it in MainActivity(It works)

Comment: Have you tried calling `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` setting a layout for the `SplashActivity` before calling `checkConnection()`?

Comment: @MatPag Nothing changes. :/

Comment: I will post the last solution i can think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add context.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;

    checkConnection();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

///////

Change this line:

```
AlertDialog.Builder connectionAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

To:

```
AlertDialog.Builder connectionAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: Make sure you also inflate the layout within your SplashActivity's onCreate, do it below super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); and register the new activity on your manifest file if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue because you call finish on the splash activity !
why you have to finish it although you need to show alert dialog on its context !

check your logcat you will find this

> YourActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40704090 that was originally added here

you can remove finish activity .. and move finish activity action to be one of the dialog buttons actions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an `AlertDialog` with the `SplashActivity` context, but you are finishing your `SplashActivity` right after and the context where the `AlertDialog` belongs no longer exists.

Considering that you want to move to your second activity, `MainActivity`, only before you choose `Enable` when you are showing this message `We recommend to use wifi, enable it?`. What you can do is something like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        checkConnection();
    }


    void checkConnection() {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        AlertDialog.Builder connectionAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        if (wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            // Do nothing
        } else if (mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

            connectionAlert.setMessage("We recommend to use wifi, enable it?");
            connectionAlert.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Wifi has been enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            connectionAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            connectionAlert.show();

        } else {

            connectionAlert.setMessage("Please, enable internet connection!");
            connectionAlert.setNeutralButton("Wifi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Wifi has been enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            connectionAlert.setNeutralButton("Mobile Data", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Mobile Data has been enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            connectionAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            connectionAlert.show();

        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of options here. But the important thing is that actually you are showing the `AlertDialog` but you are not being able to see it because you are starting another activity and finishing the `SplashActivity`, destroying the context (`this`) where the `AlertDialog` was first instantiated `new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`.